# paypal Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent

Tags: php, paypal

**fatal error: access parent:: when current class scope has no parent.**

when using sdk-core-php for paypal.

**My code is:**

```
    $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(client_id, secret));
    $apiContext->setConfig(array(
        'mode' => 'Live',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled' => false,
        'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
    ));
    try {
        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $apiContext);
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: why the code show fatal error?